# XSLT 1.0 - Change/add namespace to nodes

Tags: xslt, namespaces, mapping, xslt-1.0

I am currently trying to create an XSLT 1.0 mapping in SAP PI to change/add namespace of specific nodes. Given the Input.xml I have to create a XSL-file to get the Output.xml as you can see below. Unfortunately all my attempts were not successful so far. I would be happy if anybody can provide an XSL sheet to solve this issue. I would be glad if someone could help me, as I am already very close to despair.

Input.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:serviceABC xmlns:ns0="http://namespaceToReplace">
    <XYZ>
        <Zugang>
            <MandantCode>test</MandantCode>
            <BenutzerId>test</BenutzerId>
            <Password>test</Password>
        </Zugang>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000001</GpCode>
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000002</GpCode>
            <Name>Name2</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000003</GpCode>
            <Name>Name3</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000004</GpCode>
            <Name>Name4</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
    </XYZ>
</ns0:serviceABC>
```

Output.XML ("ns0:" - prefix needs to be removed, "xmlns="http://newNamespace1"" has to be replaced in node serviceABC, "xmlns="http://newNamespace2"" has to be added to node XYZ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceABC xmlns="http://newNamespace1">
    <XYZ xmlns="http://newNamespace2">
        <Zugang>
            <MandantCode>test</MandantCode>
            <BenutzerId>test</BenutzerId>
            <Password>test</Password>
        </Zugang>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000001</GpCode>
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000002</GpCode>
            <Name>Name2</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000003</GpCode>
            <Name>Name3</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
        <Personen>
            <GpCode>0000000004</GpCode>
            <Name>Name4</Name>
            <LandCode>DE</LandCode>
        </Personen>
    </XYZ>
</serviceABC>
```

I am looking forward hearing from you guys.

Source code developed that did not work at all

Comment: Namespaces are often misunderstood. This is why I answered your question - even though it should have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

> "xmlns="http://newNamespace2"" has to be added to node XYZ):

I don't think you understand the nature of your task. This is not a matter of adding a namespace declaration to a single node.

In your output, the `XYZ` element **and all its descendants** have been moved into the new namespace. That means they **all** have to be renamed (as does the root `ns0:serviceABC` element):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://namespaceToReplace"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:serviceABC">
    <serviceABC xmlns="http://newNamespace1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </serviceABC>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://newNamespace2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```